# Android AudioRecord - how to get average volume for a minute

Tags: java, android, audio, record

I have an AudioRecord feature I've built and for a recorded minute, I want to get the average volume in decibels. I can't figure out how to do this though. I can't even figure out if the AudioRecord object is giving me the full minute of recorded data in that the buffer array.

Here's the code I've got so far, could someone help me adapt it? I've tried to find a way to do it online but I haven't found anything yet.

```
Runnable mrHandlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ar.stop();
                short[] buffer = new short[minSize];
                Log.d("LEN: " , ""+buffer.length);
                ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
                int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                Double avg = 0.0;
                for (short s : buffer)
                {
                    if (Math.abs(s) > max)
                    {
                        max = Math.abs(s);
                    }
                    if (Math.abs(s) < min)
                    {
                        min = Math.abs(s);
                    }
                    avg = avg+Math.abs(s);
                }
                avg = avg/buffer.length;

                ar.startRecording();

            }
        };
        mrHandler.postDelayed(mrHandlerRunnable, 60000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class NoiseRecorder 
{

private final String TAG = SoundOfTheCityConstants.TAG;
public static double REFERENCE = 0.00002;

public double getNoiseLevel() throws NoValidNoiseLevelException
{
    Logging.e(TAG, "start new recording process");
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    //making the buffer bigger....
    bufferSize=bufferSize*4;
    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

    short data [] = new short[bufferSize];
    double average = 0.0;
    recorder.startRecording();
    //recording data;
    recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

    recorder.stop();
    Logging.e(TAG, "stop");
    for (short s : data)
    {
        if(s>0)
        {
            average += Math.abs(s);
        }
        else
        {
            bufferSize--;
        }
    }
    //x=max;
    double x = average/bufferSize;
    Logging.e(TAG, ""+x);
    recorder.release();
    Logging.d(TAG, "getNoiseLevel() ");
    double db=0;
    if (x==0){
        NoValidNoiseLevelException e = new NoValidNoiseLevelException(x);
        throw e;
    }
    // calculating the pascal pressure based on the idea that the max amplitude (between 0 and 32767) is 
    // relative to the pressure
    double pressure = x/51805.5336; //the value 51805.5336 can be derived from asuming that x=32767=0.6325 Pa and x=1 = 0.00002 Pa (the reference value)
    Logging.d(TAG, "x="+pressure +" Pa");
    db = (20 * Math.log10(pressure/REFERENCE));
    Logging.d(TAG, "db="+db);
    if(db>0)
    {
        return db;
    }
    NoValidNoiseLevelException e = new NoValidNoiseLevelException(x);
    throw e;
}
}
```

This calculates the average amplitude of the audio in 4 second sample. And once the average amplitude is obtained, it is then converted to `db`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. I'm guessing bufferSize=bufferSize*4; is because we want 4 seconds in this case? I'm also wondering, do you know why all the examples take Math.abs(amp)?

Comment: From what I understood, the amplitude values lies between -32768 to 32767 , so the `abs()` takes the absolute value for this purpose.  The default android's `.getMaxAmplitude()` also does this and returns an absolute value

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice!

Comment: Why do we need to call `Math.abs` here if we have `if(s > 0)` check before?

Comment: what is the reference value?